# Node.js error(NPM Error)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I just bought a VPS that's running Ubuntu 14.4 and i installed Nodejs 1.4, but when i run my script(`node tradebot.js`) it just says this error! :-/

> module.js:327
>       throw err;
>       ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'is-property'
>
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
>
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
>
> at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
>
> at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
>    at Object.  (/home/Eazyskinz/node_modules/steamcommunity-mobile-confirmations/node_modules/request/node_modules/harvalidator/node_modules/is-my-json-valid/node_modules/generate-object-property/index.js:1:80)
>
> at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
>
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
>
> at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
>
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
>
> at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
>
> at require (internal/module.js:12:17)

I'm not the expert in Ubuntu, so pleeeasy help! :-)

Comment: Try `npm install is-property` in your terminal

Comment: Then it says: is-property@1.0.2 node_modules/is-property

Comment: does your script work now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't have anything to do with Ubuntu. Your script requires `is-property` package that seems to be missing. You can fix this by executing the following from the same directory you are running the script from:

```
npm install is-property
```

There might be other modules missing. You can install them in the same fashion or if your script comes with a `package.json` file install all the dependencies at once:

```
npm install
```

For more information, see [`npm install` docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install).

Comment: Do this from the node application's directory.

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install is-property --save
```

`--save` helps to later when code deployment,it saves `is-property` version in `package.json`

Comment: Save won't do anything unless you have a `package.json` file.